# 3D 1st Person Snake Game #2

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, dom, snake-game

This is an iterative review of this question: [3D 1st Person Snake Game #1](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/194222/3d-1st-person-snake-game)
The next iteration can be found here: [3D 1st Person Snake Game #3](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/194407/3d-1st-person-snake-game-3)
Here is a snippet of the code:

```html
<html>
  <style>
    canvas{
      position:fixed;
      left:0;
      top:0;
      width:99%;
      height:99%;
    }
    * {
      padding:0px;
      margin:0px
    }
    #score,#speed,#highscore,#maxspeed,#lag,#debug{
      position: fixed;
      z-index: 100;
      font-size:20px;
      font-family:Verdana;
      left:15px;
      width: 100%;
    }
    #gameover{
      position:absolute;
      z-index: 100;
      font-size:60px;
      font-family:Verdana;
      margin: 0;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      opacity:0;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }
    #maxspeed, #score, #josh, #speed, #highscore, #lag {
      display:block;
    }
    #maxspeed {
      width: 100%;
      top:50px;
      display:none;
    }

    #score {
      top: 10px;
    }
    #speed {
      top: 30px;
    }

    #highscore {
      top:30px;
    }

    #lag {
      top: 70px;
    }
  </style>
  <div id="stats">
    <div id="debug"></div>
    <div id="score">Score: 0</div>
    <div id="speed">Speed: 1</div>
    <div id="highscore">Highscore: 1</div>
    <div id="maxspeed">Highest Speed: 1</div>
    <span id="lag">Lag: 0ms</span>
    <div id="gameover" align="center">Game Over</div>
  </div>
  <div id="canvas"></div>
  <p id="p"></p>
  <p id="e"></p>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/alexgibson/shake.js/master/shake.js"></script>
  <script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    //========================
    // One times
    //========================
    const random = Math.random,
          floor = function(a){ return ~~a},
          newGeometry = THREE.Geometry,
          newBufferGeometry = THREE.BufferGeometry,
          newMesh = THREE.Mesh,
          newLineSegments = THREE.LineSegments,
          newMeshBasicMaterial = THREE.MeshBasicMaterial,
          newVector3 = THREE.Vector3,
          newLineBasicMaterial = THREE.LineBasicMaterial,
          newBoxGeometry = THREE.BoxGeometry,
          newBoxBufferGeometry = THREE.BoxBufferGeometry,
          arena = new THREE.Group(),
          applegeometry = new THREE.SphereBufferGeometry( 0.5, 32, 32 ),
          superapplematerial= new newMeshBasicMaterial({color:"gold"}),
          applematerial= new newMeshBasicMaterial({color:"limegreen"}),
          floormaterial = new newMeshBasicMaterial({color:"lightgrey"}),
          wallmaterial = new newMeshBasicMaterial( { color: "grey" } ),
          linecube = new newBoxBufferGeometry( 1,1,1 ),
          edges = new THREE.EdgesGeometry( linecube ),
          geometry = new newBoxBufferGeometry( 1,1,1 ),
          stringify = JSON.stringify


  </script>
  <script id="script">
    (function(THREE,ArenaWidth, ArenaLength){
      'use strict'
      const arenaLines = new THREE.Group(),
            arenaWall = new newGeometry(),
            arenaFloor = new newGeometry(),
            wall1 = new newBoxGeometry( ArenaWidth+1, 1, 1 )
      .translate((ArenaWidth/2)-2,1,-2);
      arenaWall.merge(wall1);
      arenaWall.merge(wall1.translate(0,0, ArenaLength));
      const wall2 = new newBoxGeometry( 1, 1, ArenaLength+1 ).translate(ArenaWidth-2,1,(ArenaLength/2)-2);
      arenaWall.merge(wall2);
      arenaWall.merge(wall2.translate(-ArenaWidth,0,0));
      arenaFloor.merge(new newBoxGeometry( ArenaWidth+1, 1, ArenaLength+1 ).translate((ArenaWidth/2)-2,0,(ArenaLength/2)-2))
      arenaWall.mergeVertices()
      arenaFloor.mergeVertices()
      // Get the meshs
      window.arenaWallMesh = new newMesh(arenaWall, wallmaterial);
      window.arenaFloorMesh = new newMesh(arenaFloor, floormaterial);

      var speed = 100,
          maxwidth = 40,
          maxdepdth = 40,
          size = 0.5,
          score = 0,
          maxheight = 0,
          lagNum = 0,
          highscoreNum,
          showlag,
          maxspeedNum,
          showmaxspeed,
          showhighscore

      //========================
      // Threejs
      //========================

      var scene = new THREE.Scene(),
          camera= new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75,window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight,0.1,60),
          renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer(),
          extrasLookup = {
            1:30,
            2:50,
            3:70,
            4:90
          }
      //========================
      // Reductions
      //========================
      const newScene = THREE.Scene

      if(true /*localStorage.getItem("3dhighscore")==undefined*/){
        highscoreNum=0
      } else {
        highscoreNum = localStorage.getItem("3dhighscore")
      }
      if(true /*localStorage.getItem("showlag")==undefined*/){
        showlag=false
      } else {
        showlag = localStorage.getItem("showlag")
      }
      if(true /*localStorage.getItem("3dmaxspeed")==undefined*/){
        maxspeedNum=100
      } else {
        maxspeedNum = localStorage.getItem("3dmaxspeed")
      }
      if(showmaxspeed==undefined){
        showmaxspeed=false
      }
      if(showhighscore==undefined){
        showhighscore=false
      }

      renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
      document.getElementById("canvas").appendChild( renderer.domElement );

      function animate() {
        requestAnimationFrame( animate )
        renderer.render( scene, camera );
      }
      class Location{
        constructor(x,y,z){
          return [x,y,z]
        }
      }

      //========================
      // Dom
      //========================
      const maxSpeedDom = document.getElementById("maxspeed"),
            maxSpeedDomStyle = maxSpeedDom.style,
            lagdom = document.getElementById("lag"),
            lagdomstyle = lagdom.style,
            highScoreDom = document.getElementById("highscore"),
            highScoreDomStyle = highScoreDom.style,
            scoredom = document.getElementById("score"),
            speeddom = document.getElementById("speed"),
            gameOverDom = document.getElementById("gameover"),
            gameOverDomStyle = gameOverDom.style;
      //========================
      // Snake
      //========================
      class Snake {
        constructor(){
          this.segments = [
            new Location(7,1,5),
            new Location(6,1,5),
            new Location(5,1,5)
          ];
          this.direction = "forwards";
          this.nextDirection = "forwards";
          this.nextHead = new Location(8,1,5);
        }
        draw(){
          let snakeobject = new THREE.Group();
          let j = this.segments.length
          this.segments.forEach((item,index) => {
            let i = index
            let segmentColor=`rgb(${255-(255/j|0)*index+randomNumberBetween(-(j-index),j-index)},00,00)`
            const cube = new newMesh(geometry, new newMeshBasicMaterial({ color: segmentColor})),
                  x = item[0],
                  y = item[1],
                  z = item[2];
            let pos = new newVector3(x,y,z)

            const line = new newLineSegments(edges, new newLineBasicMaterial({ color: segmentColor,linewidth:2 }));
            cube.position.copy(pos);
            line.position.copy(pos);
            snakeobject.add(line,cube);
          })
          scene.add(snakeobject);
        }
        move() {
          this.segments.unshift(this.nextHead);
          if(this.checkCollision()) {
            this.segments.shift();
            gameOver();
            return;
          };
          var nextHeadPos = this.nextHead;
          this.direction = this.nextDirection;
          (directionSwitch[this.direction])(nextHeadPos)
          if(stringify(this.segments[0]) === stringify(apple.pos)) {
            speed=0.95*speed;
            score++;
            if(apple.type === "superapple") {
              speed = 1.10*speed;
              score += 4;
            }
            apple.move();
          } else {
            this.segments.pop();
          };
        }
        changeDirection(key) {
          switch(key){
            case 39:
            case 68:
            case 37:
            case 65:
              keyLookup[key][this.direction]()
              break;
            case 192:
            case 55:
            case 56:
              keyLookup[key]()
              break;
                    }
        }
        checkCollision() {
          const head = this.segments[0]
          const headz = head[2];
          const headx = head[0];
          const wallCollision = headz === -2 || headz === ArenaLength-2 || headx === -2 || headx === ArenaWidth-2;
          var selfCollision = false;
          this.segments.forEach(function(item, index) {
            if(index) {
              if(item[0] === head[0] && item[2] === head[2]) {
                selfCollision = true;
              };
            };
          });
          const collision = selfCollision || wallCollision;
          return collision;
        }
      }

      //========================
      // Drawing
      //========================
      function drawStats() {
        var extras = 1;
        if(score > highscoreNum) {
          highscoreNum = score;
          //localStorage.setItem("3dhighscore", highscore);
        }
        if(speed < maxspeed) {
          maxspeedNum = speed;
          //localStorage.setItem("3dmaxspeed", maxspeed);
        }

        scoredom.innerHTML=`Score: ${score}`;
        speeddom.innerHTML=`Speed: ${(((100/speed*100)|0)/100)}`;

        if(showhighscore) {
          extras++;
          highscore.style.display = "block";
          highscore.style.top = extrasLookup[extras]
          highscore.innerHTML = `Highscore: ${highscoreNum}`;

        } else {
          highScoreDomStyle.display = "none";
        };

        if(showmaxspeed) {
          extras++;
          maxspeed.style.display = "block";
          maxspeed.style.top = extrasLookup[extras]
          maxspeed.innerHTML = `Highest Speed: ${(((100/maxspeed*100)|0)/100)}`;
        } else {
          maxspeed.style.display = "none";
        };

        if(showlag) {
          extras++;
          lag.style.display = "block";
          lag.style.top = extrasLookup[extras]
          lag.innerHTML = `Lag: ${lagNum}ms`;
        } else {
          lagdomstyle.display = "none";
        };
      }
      function renderArena() {
        ;
      }

      //========================
      // Apple
      //========================
      class Apple {
        constructor(){
          this.pos = new Location(2,1,2)
        }
        move(){

          // Set the location to a random x and z.
          var x = randomNumberBetween(0,ArenaWidth-4)
          var z = randomNumberBetween(0,ArenaLength-4)
          this.pos = new Location(x,1,z)
          if(randomNumberBetween(1,11)===1&&score>15){                  
            apple.type="superapple"
          } else {
            apple.type="apple"
          }
        }
        draw() {
          var sphere

          // Generate a new sphere.
          if(this.type=="superapple") {
            sphere = new newMesh( applegeometry, superapplematerial );
          } else {
            sphere = new newMesh( applegeometry, applematerial );
          }

          // Get the data location.
          var applepos=apple.pos

          // Set the location of the visual apple to the data location.
          sphere.position.set(applepos[0],applepos[1],applepos[2])
          scene.add(sphere);
        }
      }
      //========================
      // Misc
      //========================
      function newGame(key) {
        if(key==82) {

          // Stop the game.
          clearTimeout(gameLoop);
          s=function(){};

          // Start a new game.
          var game = document.getElementById("canvas");
          game.removeChild(game.childNodes[0]);
          eval(document.getElementById("script").innerHTML);
        }
      }
      gameOverDomStyle.opacity=0;
      function gameOver() {
        s = function() {
          camera.position.copy(new newVector3((ArenaWidth/2)-2,Math.sqrt(
            Math.pow(ArenaWidth/2,2)+Math.pow(ArenaLength/2,2)),(ArenaLength/2)-2));
          camera.lookAt(new newVector3((ArenaWidth/2)-2,0,(ArenaLength/2)-2));
        };
        document.onkeydown=function(e) {
          newGame(e.keyCode);    
        }
        //listen to shake event
        var shakeEvent = new Shake({threshold: 15});
        shakeEvent.start();
        window.addEventListener('shake', function(){
          newGame(82)
        }, false);

        //stop listening
        function stopShake(){
          shakeEvent.stop();
        }

        //check if shake is supported or not.
        if(!("ondevicemotion" in window)){alert("Not Supported");}
        gameOverDomStyle.opacity = 1;
      }

      function randomNumberBetween(a,b) {
        return a+floor(random()*(b-a));
      }
      var apple = new Apple(),
          snake = new Snake()
      var directionSwitch={
        "forwards":function(a){this.nextHead = new Location(a[0]+1, a[1], a[2])},
        "backwards":function(a){this.nextHead = new Location(a[0]-1, a[1], a[2])},
        "left":function(a){this.nextHead = new Location(a[0], a[1], a[2]-1)},
        "right":function(a){this.nextHead = new Location(a[0], a[1], a[2]+1)}
      }
      for(var x in directionSwitch){
        directionSwitch[x] = directionSwitch[x].bind(snake)
      }
      var right = {
        "right":function(){this.nextDirection = "backwards"},
        "backwards":function(){this.nextDirection = "left"},
        "forwards":function(){this.nextDirection = "right"},
        "left":function(){this.nextDirection = "forwards"}
      }
      for(var x in right){
        right[x] = right[x].bind(snake)
      }
      var left = {
        "right":function(){snake.nextDirection = "forwards"},
        "forwards":function(){snake.nextDirection = "left"},
        "left":function(){snake.nextDirection = "backwards"},
        "backwards":function(){snake.nextDirection = "right"}
      }
      for(var x in left){
        left[x] = left[x].bind(snake)
      }
      var keyLookup = {
        "39":right,
        "68":right,
        "37":left,
        "65":left,
        "192":function(){showlag=!showlag},
        "55":function(){showhighscore=!showhighscore},
        "56":function(){showmaxspeed = !showmaxspeed}
      }
      snake.draw();
      apple.move();

      var background = new THREE.Color( "white" ),
          fog = new THREE.FogExp2( "random", 0.02625 );

      let s = function() {
        // Start for lag detection.
        var start = performance.now();

        // Make a fresh scene.
        scene = new newScene();

        // Move the snake.
        snake.move();

        // Render various things onto the scene.
        scene.add(arenaWallMesh,arenaFloorMesh)
        snake.draw();
        apple.draw();
        drawStats();


        // Get relevent snake parts.
        let head = snake.segments[0];
        let nextHead = snake.nextHead;

        // Set camera position and target.
        camera.position.set(head[0],head[1],head[2]);
        camera.lookAt(new newVector3(nextHead[0],nextHead[1],nextHead[2]));

        // Set background and fog.
        scene.background = background;
        scene.fog = fog;
        let end = performance.now();
        // Reschedule the next update
        gameLoop = setTimeout(function(){
          requestAnimationFrame(s)
        },speed)

        // End for lag detection and calculation of lag.
        lagNum = floor((end-start))
      }
      animate()
      var gameLoop = setTimeout(function(){
        requestAnimationFrame(s)
      },speed);
      document.onkeydown = function(e) {
        snake.changeDirection(e.keyCode);
      }
    })(window.THREE, (((window.innerWidth/10)|0)*10-2*10)/10, (((window.innerHeight/10)|0)*10-2*10)/10)
  </script>
```

Comment: Note: For the snippet, click "run", "Full page", purposely lose, and then click "r". Unfortunately the snippet makes the game small...

Comment: Oh maaan. It's so hard to play. Sorry, now got zero time to write an actual review!  https://i.stack.imgur.com/gfiZi.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Feedback

I like how the DOM elements are stored in constants at the beginning of the code. It seems that a lot of the feedback from previous answers has been incorporated, except a few things like resetting the game without using `eval()`, and other es-6 features like classes. The CSS styles look succinct and appear to be sufficient.

#### Suggestions/Comments

- In the function `checkCollision()` it might be fitting to use [Array.prototype.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) instead of assigning the value of a boolean inside the callback of a `forEach()`. Also, that loop call comes after the check for a wall collision - if there is a wall collision, the function could immediately return `true` instead of also looping through the segments.
- As was mentioned by samurai8 in [the answer to your previous review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/194304/120114) there are still places where `var` is used instead of `let`
- [Blindman's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/194173/120114) on the first game mentioned using semi-colons - it appears most lines have them but some still don't.
- The HTML snippet doesn't have a `<body>` tag - apparently it still works and perhaps you have one in other environments but it feels weird not to have one.
- The event listener for *shake* could be simplified: Use [Function.prototype.bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to create a [partially applied function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Partially_applied_functions):

  > ```
  > window.addEventListener('shake', function(){
  >   newGame(82)
  > }, false);
  > ```

  Can be simplified to:

  ```
  window.addEventListener('shake', newGame.bind(null,82), false);
  ```