# 3D 1st Person Snake Game #3

Tags: javascript, game, ecmascript-6, dom, snake-game

Final iteration of an iterative review.
The previous iteration is here: [3D 1st Person Snake Game #2](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/194377/3d-1st-person-snake-game-2)

Note: For the snippet, click <kbd>run</kbd>, "Full page", purposely lose, and then type <kbd>r</kbd>.

Here is the snippet:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      canvas{
        position:fixed;
        left:0;
        top:0;
        width:99%;
        height:99%;
      }
      * {
        padding:0px;
        margin:0px
      }
      #score,#speed,#highscore,#maxspeed,#lag,#debug{
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 100;
        font-size:20px;
        font-family:Verdana;
        left:15px;
        width: 100%;
      }
      #gameover{
        position:absolute;
        z-index: 100;
        font-size:60px;
        font-family:Verdana;
        margin: 0;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        opacity:0;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      }
      #maxspeed, #score, #josh, #speed, #highscore, #lag {
        display:block;
      }
      #maxspeed {
        width: 100%;
        top:50px;
        display:none;
      }

      #score {
        top: 10px;
      }
      #speed {
        top: 30px;
      }

      #highscore {
        top:30px;
      }

      #lag {
        top: 70px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="stats">
      <div id="debug"></div>
      <div id="score">Score: 0</div>
      <div id="speed">Speed: 1</div>
      <div id="highscore">Highscore: 1</div>
      <div id="maxspeed">Highest Speed: 1</div>
      <span id="lag">Lag: 0ms</span>
      <div id="gameover" align="center">Game Over</div>
    </div>
    <div id="canvas"></div>
    <p id="p"></p>
    <p id="e"></p>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/alexgibson/shake.js/master/shake.js"></script>
    <script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      //========================
      // One times
      //========================
      const random = Math.random,
            floor = function(a){ return ~~a},
            newGeometry = THREE.Geometry,
            newBufferGeometry = THREE.BufferGeometry,
            newMesh = THREE.Mesh,
            newLineSegments = THREE.LineSegments,
            newMeshBasicMaterial = THREE.MeshBasicMaterial,
            newVector3 = THREE.Vector3,
            newLineBasicMaterial = THREE.LineBasicMaterial,
            newBoxGeometry = THREE.BoxGeometry,
            newBoxBufferGeometry = THREE.BoxBufferGeometry,
            arena = new THREE.Group(),
            applegeometry = new THREE.SphereBufferGeometry( 0.5, 32, 32 ),
            superapplematerial= new newMeshBasicMaterial({color:"gold"}),
            applematerial= new newMeshBasicMaterial({color:"limegreen"}),
            floormaterial = new newMeshBasicMaterial({color:"lightgrey"}),
            wallmaterial = new newMeshBasicMaterial( { color: "grey" } ),
            linecube = new newBoxBufferGeometry( 1,1,1 ),
            edges = new THREE.EdgesGeometry( linecube ),
            geometry = new newBoxBufferGeometry( 1,1,1 ),
            stringify = JSON.stringify


    </script>
    <script id="script">
      (function(THREE,ArenaWidth, ArenaLength){
        'use strict'
        const arenaLines = new THREE.Group(),
              arenaWall = new newGeometry(),
              arenaFloor = new newGeometry(),
              wall1 = new newBoxGeometry(
                ArenaWidth+1,
                1,
                1 
              ).translate(
                ArenaWidth/2-2,
                1,
                -2
              ),
              wall2 = new newBoxGeometry(
                1,
                1,
                ArenaLength+1
              ).translate(
                ArenaWidth-2,
                1,
                ArenaLength/2-2
              );
        arenaWall.merge(wall1);
        arenaWall.merge(wall1.translate(0,0, ArenaLength))
        arenaWall.merge(wall2);
        arenaWall.merge(wall2.translate(-ArenaWidth,0,0));
        arenaFloor.merge(new newBoxGeometry( ArenaWidth+1, 1, ArenaLength+1 ).translate((ArenaWidth/2)-2,0,(ArenaLength/2)-2))
        arenaWall.mergeVertices()
        arenaFloor.mergeVertices()
        // Get the meshs
        window.arenaWallMesh = new newMesh(arenaWall, wallmaterial);
        window.arenaFloorMesh = new newMesh(arenaFloor, floormaterial);

        var speed = 100,
            maxwidth = 40,
            maxdepdth = 40,
            size = 0.5,
            score = 0,
            maxheight = 0,
            lagNum = 0,
            highscoreNum,
            showlag,
            maxspeedNum,
            showmaxspeed,
            showhighscore

        //========================
        // Threejs
        //========================

        var scene = new THREE.Scene(),
            camera= new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75,window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight,0.1,60),
            renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer(),
            extrasLookup = {
              1:30,
              2:50,
              3:70,
              4:90
            }
        //========================
        // Reductions
        //========================
        const newScene = THREE.Scene

        if(true /*localStorage.getItem("3dhighscore")==undefined*/){
          highscoreNum=0
        } else {
          highscoreNum = localStorage.getItem("3dhighscore")
        }
        if(true /*localStorage.getItem("showlag")==undefined*/){
          showlag=false
        } else {
          showlag = localStorage.getItem("showlag")
        }
        if(true /*localStorage.getItem("3dmaxspeed")==undefined*/){
          maxspeedNum=100
        } else {
          maxspeedNum = localStorage.getItem("3dmaxspeed")
        }
        if(showmaxspeed==undefined){
          showmaxspeed=false
        }
        if(showhighscore==undefined){
          showhighscore=true
        }

        renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
        document.getElementById("canvas").appendChild( renderer.domElement );

        function animate() {
          requestAnimationFrame( animate )
          renderer.render( scene, camera );
        }
        class Location{
          constructor(x,y,z){
            return [x,y,z]
          }
        }

        //========================
        // Dom
        //========================
        const maxSpeedDom = document.getElementById("maxspeed"),
              maxSpeedDomStyle = maxSpeedDom.style,
              lagdom = document.getElementById("lag"),
              lagdomstyle = lagdom.style,
              highScoreDom = document.getElementById("highscore"),
              highScoreDomStyle = highScoreDom.style,
              scoredom = document.getElementById("score"),
              speeddom = document.getElementById("speed"),
              gameOverDom = document.getElementById("gameover"),
              gameOverDomStyle = gameOverDom.style;
        //========================
        // Snake
        //========================
        class Snake {
          constructor(){
            this.segments = [
              new Location(7,1,5),
              new Location(6,1,5),
              new Location(5,1,5)
            ];
            this.direction = "forwards";
            this.nextDirection = "forwards";
            this.nextHead = new Location(8,1,5);
          }
          draw(){
            let snakeobject = new THREE.Group();
            let j = this.segments.length;
            this.segments.forEach((item,index) => {
              let i = index
              let segmentColor=`rgb(${255-(255/j|0)*index+randomNumberBetween(-(j-index),j-index)},00,00)`
              const cube = new newMesh(geometry, new newMeshBasicMaterial({ color: segmentColor})),
                    x = item[0],
                    y = item[1],
                    z = item[2];
              let pos = new newVector3(x,y,z)

              const line = new newLineSegments(edges, new newLineBasicMaterial({ color: segmentColor,linewidth:2 }));
              cube.position.copy(pos);
              line.position.copy(pos);
              snakeobject.add(line,cube);
            })
            scene.add(snakeobject);
          }
          move() {
            this.segments.unshift(this.nextHead);
            if(this.checkCollision()) {
              this.segments.shift();
              gameOver();
              return;
            };
            var nextHeadPos = this.nextHead;
            this.direction = this.nextDirection;
            (directionSwitch[this.direction])(nextHeadPos);
            if(stringify(this.segments[0]) === stringify(apple.pos)) {
              speed=0.95*speed;
              score++;
              if(apple.type === "superapple") {
                speed = 1.10*speed;
                score += 4;
              }
              apple.move();
            } else {
              this.segments.pop();
            };
          }
          changeDirection(key) {
            switch(key){
              case 39:
              case 68:
              case 37:
              case 65:
                keyLookup[key][this.direction]();
                break;
              case 192:
              case 55:
              case 56:
                keyLookup[key]();
                break;
                      }
          }
          checkCollision() {
            const head = this.segments[0];
            const headz = head[2];
            const headx = head[0];
            const wallCollision = headz === -2 || headz === ArenaLength-2 || headx === -2 || headx === ArenaWidth-2;
            if(wallCollision){return true};
            const selfCollision = this.segments.some((item, index) => {
              if(index) {
                if(item[0] === head[0] && item[2] === head[2]) {
                  return true;
                };
              };
            });
            if(selfCollision){return true};
            return false;
          }
        }

        //========================
        // Drawing
        //========================
        function drawStats() {
          var extras = 1;
          if(score > highscoreNum) {
            highscoreNum = score;
            //localStorage.setItem("3dhighscore", highscore);
          }
          if(speed < maxspeed) {
            maxspeedNum = speed;
            //localStorage.setItem("3dmaxspeed", maxspeed);
          }

          scoredom.innerHTML=`Score: ${score}`;
          speeddom.innerHTML=`Speed: ${(((100/speed*100)|0)/100)}`;

          if(showhighscore) {
            extras++;
            highscore.style.display = "block";
            highscore.style.top = extrasLookup[extras];
            highscore.innerHTML = `Highscore: ${highscoreNum}`;

          } else {
            highScoreDomStyle.display = "none";
          };

          if(showmaxspeed) {
            extras++;
            maxspeed.style.display = "block";
            maxspeed.style.top = extrasLookup[extras];
            maxspeed.innerHTML = `Highest Speed: ${(((100/maxspeed*100)|0)/100)}`;
          } else {
            maxspeed.style.display = "none";
          };

          if(showlag) {
            extras++;
            lag.style.display = "block";
            lag.style.top = extrasLookup[extras];
            lag.innerHTML = `Lag: ${lagNum}ms`;
          } else {
            lagdomstyle.display = "none";
          };
        };

        //========================
        // Apple
        //========================
        class Apple {
          constructor(){
            this.pos = new Location(2,1,2);
          }
          move(){

            // Set the location to a random x and z.
            const x = randomNumberBetween(0,ArenaWidth-4);
            const z = randomNumberBetween(0,ArenaLength-4);
            this.pos = new Location(x,1,z);
            if(randomNumberBetween(1,11)===1&&score>15){                  
              apple.type="superapple";
            } else {
              apple.type="apple";
            };
          }
          draw() {
            var sphere = this.type === "superapple" ? new newMesh( applegeometry, superapplematerial ) : new newMesh( applegeometry, applematerial );

            // Get the data location.
            var applepos=apple.pos;

            // Set the location of the visual apple to the data location.
            sphere.position.set(applepos[0],applepos[1],applepos[2]);
            scene.add(sphere);
          }
        }
        //========================
        // Misc
        //========================
        function newGame(key) {
          if(key==82) {

            // Stop the game.
            clearTimeout(gameLoop);
            s=function(){};

            // Start a new game.
            var game = document.getElementById("canvas");
            game.removeChild(game.childNodes[0]);
            eval(document.getElementById("script").innerHTML);
          }
        }
        gameOverDomStyle.opacity=0;
        function gameOver() {
          s = function() {
            camera.position.copy(new newVector3((ArenaWidth/2)-2,Math.sqrt(
              Math.pow(ArenaWidth/2,2)+Math.pow(ArenaLength/2,2)),(ArenaLength/2)-2));
            camera.lookAt(new newVector3((ArenaWidth/2)-2,0,(ArenaLength/2)-2));
          };
          document.onkeydown=function(e) {
            newGame(e.keyCode);    
          };
          //listen to shake event
          var shakeEvent = new Shake({threshold: 15});
          shakeEvent.start();
          window.addEventListener('shake', newGame.bind(false,82), false);

          //stop listening
          function stopShake(){
            shakeEvent.stop();
          };

          //check if shake is supported or not.
          if(!("ondevicemotion" in window)){alert("Not Supported");}
          gameOverDomStyle.opacity = 1;
        };

        function randomNumberBetween(a,b) {
          return a+floor(random()*(b-a));
        };
        var apple = new Apple(),
            snake = new Snake();
        var directionSwitch={
          "forwards":function(a){this.nextHead = new Location(a[0]+1, a[1], a[2])},
          "backwards":function(a){this.nextHead = new Location(a[0]-1, a[1], a[2])},
          "left":function(a){this.nextHead = new Location(a[0], a[1], a[2]-1)},
          "right":function(a){this.nextHead = new Location(a[0], a[1], a[2]+1)}
        };
        for(var x in directionSwitch){
          directionSwitch[x] = directionSwitch[x].bind(snake);
        };
        var right = {
          "right":function(){this.nextDirection = "backwards"},
          "backwards":function(){this.nextDirection = "left"},
          "forwards":function(){this.nextDirection = "right"},
          "left":function(){this.nextDirection = "forwards"}
        };
        for(var x in right){
          right[x] = right[x].bind(snake);
        };
        var left = {
          "right":function(){this.nextDirection = "forwards"},
          "forwards":function(){this.nextDirection = "left"},
          "left":function(){this.nextDirection = "backwards"},
          "backwards":function(){this.nextDirection = "right"}
        };
        for(var x in left){
          left[x] = left[x].bind(snake);
        };
        var keyLookup = {
          "39":right,
          "68":right,
          "37":left,
          "65":left,
          "192":function(){showlag=!showlag},
          "55":function(){showhighscore=!showhighscore},
          "56":function(){showmaxspeed = !showmaxspeed}
        };
        snake.draw();
        apple.move();

        var background = new THREE.Color( "white" ),
            fog = new THREE.FogExp2( "white", 0.02625 );

        let s = function() {
          // Start for lag detection.
          var start = performance.now();

          // Make a fresh scene.
          scene = new newScene();

          // Move the snake.
          snake.move();

          // Render various things onto the scene.
          scene.add(arenaWallMesh,arenaFloorMesh);
          snake.draw();
          apple.draw();
          drawStats();


          // Get relevent snake parts.
          let head = snake.segments[0];
          let nextHead = snake.nextHead;

          // Set camera position and target.
          camera.position.set(head[0],head[1],head[2]);
          camera.lookAt(new newVector3(nextHead[0],nextHead[1],nextHead[2]));

          // Set background and fog.
          scene.background = background;
          scene.fog = fog;
          let end = performance.now();
          // Reschedule the next update
          gameLoop = setTimeout(requestAnimationFrame.bind(null,s),speed);

          // End for lag detection and calculation of lag.
          lagNum = floor((end-start));
        }
        animate();
        var gameLoop = setTimeout(requestAnimationFrame.bind(null,s),speed);
        document.onkeydown = function(e) {
          snake.changeDirection(e.keyCode);
        }
      })(window.THREE, (((window.innerWidth/10)|0)*10)/10, (((window.innerHeight/10)|0)*10)/10)
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Broad Feedback

It appears that you have incorporated most of the feedback from [my answer to your previous post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/194389/120114), except for a few places where `var` is still used but `let` or `const` could be used instead.

The functions used in the misc. functions for drawing, like in the objects `left` and `right`, which get used in `keyLookup` might be more appropriate as methods in the snake class.

### Targeted Feedback

Apparently it [isn't incorrect to return a value from a constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28006379/1575353) but it does seem strange.

---

`const` could be used more for any variable that doesn’t get reassigned, like `pos` in the callback of `Snake.draw()`

---

The method `Snake. checkCollision()` could be simplified to return the result of calling `.some()` (without storing it in `selfCollision`) and  the callback function could be simplified to a single return line- perhaps just an arrow function.

```
const checkSegment = (item, index) => index && item[0] === head[0] && item[2] === head[2]);
return this.segments.some(checkSegment);
```

---

There are multiple places in `Snake.drawStats()` where `extras` has a postfix increment operator on a single line and then later the value is used. For example:

> ```
> if(showhighscore) {
>   extras++;
>   highscore.style.display = "block";
>   highscore.style.top = extrasLookup[extras];
> ```

The increment could be changed to a prefix increment and moved into the usage for the array access:

```
if(showhighscore) {
  highscore.style.display = "block";
  highscore.style.top = extrasLookup[++extras];
```

That way there isn’t an excess line just to increment that value.

And also that method  `Snake.drawStats()` seems a bit repetitive in the last three blocks that conditionally show the high score, max speed and lag. It would be wise to abstract common functionality into a helper function and call it in each place (i.e. DRY it out).

---

While I don't see it used anywhere, the function `stopShake()` could be simplified to a partial:

```
const stopShake = shakeEvent.stop();
```

If the context needs to be bound, then use `Function.bind()` for that:

```
const stopShake = shakeEvent.stop.bind(shakeEvent);
```

---

Why does `Apple.move()` utilize `apple`? It should be able to use `this` instead of the global variable...

---

Why does `Apple.draw()` use `var` for `sphere` and `applepos`? Why not use `const`?

---

These CSS rule sets could be combined unless they need to diverge

> ```
> #speed {
>   top: 30px;
> }
> #highscore {
>   top:30px;
> }
> ```

But looking at those elements it appears hard to read both when they have the same top setting. Perhaps one should be lowered to allow them to both be readable...